# Cant center div after following tutorials

Tags: html, css, chart.js

I'm having slight issues centering my div. I'm currently using Chart.js inside of a canvas.

Here is the CSS:

```
#canvas-container {
    text-align: center;
}

canvas {
   display: inline-block;
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div id="canvas-container" style="align-content: center">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

it's just floating to the left

Comment: Did you try using margin:0 auto; on canvas and setting the width of #canvas-container.

Comment: canvas is centered, tested and it's working. Maybe you have more CSS/HTML

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div> in another <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div-in-another-div)